# Tell router to make traffic only over one special ip address

Tags: networking, router

I have two routers.

A - is connected to the internet

B - is connected to A router's network

A has some clients (notebooks, computers, printers, etc.).

B has also some clients.

B clients are not allowed to see the clients inside A router's network but should be able to use A network to access the internet.

I am new at routing, networking etc. - how can I tell router B to communicate only with router A and don't show the A network clients?

Router B has DD-WRT installed.

More informations about the networks:

Network A: - router IP (static): 192.168.0.1/24 - DHCP enabled / Linksys WRT54GL (original firmware)
Network B: - router IP (static): 192.168.2.1/24 - DHCP enabled / TP-Link WR1043ND (with DD-WRT v24)

Comment: I know at least 3 solutions, but you need to give more details about e.g. the actual addressing. The easiest would be to statically configure B to add a /32 route to A and set it as default gateway, but this is not 100% fullproof if A routes blindly.

Comment: @BatchyX I added more informations to my question.

Answer (score 1):

If router B is in NAT mode, you should be able to get by with just a couple firewall rules like so:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -s 192,168.2.0/24 -d 192.168.0.1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -d 192.168.0.0/24 -j DROP
```

Where to put them in your firewall config depends on what rules you already have. You want them before the other ACCEPT rules except for any RELATED,ESTABLISHED-style conntrack rules.

Comment: The solution is (tested and working): 

Install on the ROUTER inside the **green network** the newest DD-WRT version.

After installing DD-WRT go into the Web-Admin-GUI of the **green network** router, to add **ONE** command line.

Inside the Web-Admin-GUI goto:
"Administration" --> "Commands" and add this line: 

`iptables -I FORWARD -d 192.168.0.0/24 -j DROP` *(192.168.0.0/24 is the network number of the **orange network**)*

**IMPORTANT:** that the router don't forget this line at reboot - save it with the button "Save Firewall".